# How to be consistent on filtering a refresh rate using CGI to load a html page written in C?

Tags: javascript, html, c, linux, cgi

I have a function that creates a drop down box with a set of refresh rates: 3 seconds, 10 seconds and 60 seconds. When I click on the 3 seconds the page refreshes every 3 seconds.

However when I click on the 10 seconds the form will load and the page will refresh for 10 seconds, and then it will go back to re-fresh every 3 seconds. That is because on my if statement the first option is the 3 seconds one.

I need to be consistent in reloading the form and I've tried to but it doesn't work. This is the function for the drop-down menu:

```
void pgMkOptionNum (const char *tag, int value, int selected){
httpPrintf ("<option value=\"%d\"%s>%-8s</option>",
    value, ((selected) ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""), tag);}
```

The function call is this one:

```
pgMkOptionNum("3 Seconds", FILTER_3, (filterRefresh == FILTER_3 ? 1 : 0));
pgMkOptionNum("10 Seconds", FILTER_10, (filterRefresh == FILTER_10 ? 1 : 0));
pgMkOptionNum("60 Seconds", FILTER_60, (filterRefresh == FILTER_60 ? 1 : 0));
```

Where filterRefresh is equal to 0 at the top and FILTER_X are defined at the top as 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

Comment: if(filterRefresh == FILTER_3)
    {
        httpWrite("<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"3\">");
    }
    else if(filterRefresh == FILTER_10)
    {
        httpWrite("<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"10\">");
    }
    else if(filterRefresh == FILTER_60)
    {
        httpWrite("<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"60\">");
    }

Comment: Edit your question to put the code in the question body.  It's hard to read in a comment.